# Javascript class working well on Chrome but not in Edge. Why?

Tags: javascript, html

I defined a class (as shown in the following code) which works well in Chrome but not in Edge. Using the debugger of Edge I got the following error:

> `SCRIPT1005`: Expected `(` in Line 4 and Column 11.

Do you know what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

*N.B.* `Simulation` and `PMSM` are two other objects defined in the following part of the code.

```js
class Event_Class {
  Flag_Play;
  Flag_Pause;
  Flag_Stop;
  Initialize() {
    this.Flag_Play = false;
    this.Flag_Pause = false;
    this.Flag_Stop = false;
  }
  Play() {
    this.Flag_Play = true;
    this.Flag_Pause = false;
    this.Flag_Stop = false;
  }
  Pause() {
    this.Flag_Play = false;
    this.Flag_Pause = true;
    this.Flag_Stop = false;
  }
  Stop(Simulation, PMSM) {
    this.Flag_Play = false;
    this.Flag_Pause = false;
    this.Flag_Stop = true;
    Simulation.Initialize();
    PMSM.Initialize();
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields not being fully supported in Edge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `Flag_Play`, `Flag_Pause` and `Flag_Stop` are all defined as [public fields.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields) Public fields are not supported in the current version of Edge, but will be when Edge is updated to the newer Chromium based version (which is the same platform as Chrome).

To get full support on both browsers use the `constructor` method to define your properties and assign them values there.

The constructor will be executed whenever you create a new instance.

See the example below.

```
class Event_Class {

    constructor() {
       this.Flag_Play = false;
       this.Flag_Pause = false;
       this.Flag_Stop = false;
    }

    initialize() {
```